# Create a postgres user role that can't access a specific table

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.6

I have a postgres 9.6 database with many tables. I need to create a role that doesn't have access to one of these tables.

I think I need to do a Grant Permissions, but I haven't been able to find anything to exclude a table.

```
CREATE ROLE noaccess_role;
```

But that is as far as I've got.

Comment: REVOKE ALL ON tbl FROM noaccess_role;